# Why PHPMyadmin not showing the real number of queries in a table and database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database contain a table called "**users**" that is not showing the accurate total number of queries inside that table , For example if there is **3000** queries and I added new **70** users , The number of queries became **3010** for example (Less than the new queries I inserted) , Then if I searched for a query of them for example : person called "**john**"
**1-** if I searched using **ctf+f** (I'm showing the last 500 new added queries while doing that) but I don't find him .
**2-** if I used the "filter search" above the table , I also don't find him.
But if I used **SQL** inside the database or using PHP and write :
 `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = john;`
Then I find him , How is this possible ? and why it's happening ?

Comment: If you started with 3000 ROWS and attempted to add 70 and ended up with 3010 then either 60 failed, 60 were deleted or your query is wrong (Run separately from mysql and php to discover where) what happens if you run select count(*) from users?

Comment: @P.Salmon How could the query be wrong or failed while I can find it using SQL "SELECT * FROM users Where username=john"?

Comment: Dunno you haven't shown me a query and it's not clear whether you are using phpmyadmin and/or php and you haven't confirmed a row count by query.